How to horizontally flip webcam Picture-in-Picture video
I am working on a video conferencing application and user can toggle between having their camera to be Picture-in-Picture or just on the web page. For the webpage I used a video element that would use getUserMedia stream as the srcObject and would display the current webcam. However, as the stream from the webcams are mirrored, “the wrong way around”, I used css transform to flip the video element horizontally by 180. It works fine, however, when try to enter in Picture-in-Picture mode, the video is still mirrored / "wrong way around".
I tried using :picture-in-picture in css to apply the transformation there too, however, it had no effect


const button = document.getElementById('button');
const webCamVideo = document.querySelector('.webcam-vid')

button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  webCamVideo.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
  video.play();
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    video.requestPictureInPicture()
    .catch(console.error)
  });
});
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.webcam-vid {
  transform: scaleX(-1)
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
<video class="webcam-vid" autoPlay playsInline></video>


<button class="btn btn-primary" id="button">Display Webcam feed in Picture-in-Picture mode</button>




While you can adjust styling of the elements you have control of using :picture-in-picture, I don't think you can adjust the styling of the actual picture in picture itself, I think that is outside your control (but I hope someone can tell me I am wrong).

The duplicate question confirms that you cannot adjust the Picture in Picture itself, you have to, effectively, recreate the video eg through canvas.
